# Web Form Stopped working - /<?php%20$PHP_SELF;%20?>

Tags: php, webforms

I didn't make changes to this form - it has been working since last June but for some reason this AM it is not working. I'm not a strong PHP Coder so I would love some help. Here is the form code: (I didn't write the code - just added captcha to it)

```
<div id="contact-form">
<?php if(!$_POST["sendmail"]){?>
<p>Please use the form below to contact us.</p>
<form method="post" action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>">
<p><input type="text" name="name" class="txtfield" placeholder="Name..." /> 
</p>
<p><input type="text" name="email" class="txtfield" placeholder="Email..." /> 
</p>
<p><input type="text" name="phone" class="txtfield" placeholder="Phone..." /> 
</p>
<p><textarea name="message" class="txtarea" placeholder="Message..."> 
</textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="sendmail" value="Submit" class="sbmtbtn" /></p>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data- 
sitekey="6Ldx7yMUAAAAALtSxX6Ht7YwYuNQdgcNP1sF1dAZ"></div>
</form>
<?php }else{
/* we have email so send it and then thank them. NOTE: NO ERROR CHECKING... 
*/

$mess=$_POST["name"]."\r\n".$_POST["email"]."\r\n".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n".
$_POST["message"]."\r\n";
          $to      = 'admin4@newberrytanks.com';
          $subject = 'Website Contact Form';
          $headers = 'From: admin4@newberrytanks.com' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: 
admin4@newberrytanks.com' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
          mail($to, $subject, $mess, $headers);
?>
<h2 class="red">Thanks for your submission!</h2>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: "*it is not working*" how? What is the expected result and what's the actual result?

Comment: Your captcha doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Might not be the best for you to edit your web form if you don't have experience with PHP.

Comment: `action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"` If this code was not changed in any way then it would never have worked

Comment: `<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>` does nothing, you'd need to echo that but you also should escape it.

Comment: `$PHP_SELF` is not even a variable... Just leave the `action` empty. Even if `$PHP_SELF` was supposed to be a constant you don't need `$`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, **so from your question**, visiting the site, I can see why your form is not working:

[image]

None of your PHP code is running as PHP. The server is not rendering your code, it's simply commenting it out there.

You really need to figure out what is happening with your server.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's why your server is not rendering PHP: your files are `html`.

I am highly skeptic this has ever worked. Again, PHP will not be rendered in `html` files.

Comment: Wait, what? How did you arrive to this conclusion? That's a pretty broad assumption.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Go to her page... She didn't remove the URL from the form emails. Also the code is the same; put 1 and 2 together and I feel same in making the assumption.

Comment: I see. You should really include this in your answer, it's not clear at all.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I removed the links... It's not my place to share that information. I will add the disclaimer on there.

Answer (score 0):

So again not a strong php coder. This was working until 7:05 this am, but I have updated all the pages to be php pages and now all is working as it should. My only thought is maybe our server was using old php and has since upgraded. I don't really know but I appreciate folks trying and helping a gal out. :)

Comment: No problem... I hope I was able to help. Just a thought, again, HTML won't render PHP code, maybe the files were converted by someone else?